# Не изменяется фоновый цвет

Tags: css

```
.body{
  background: #000000;
}
```

Что делать?

Comment: body {background:#000000;}

Comment: `Что делать?` - если в качестве body имелся в  виду тег, то учить основы css.

Comment: Весело под вечер

Comment: Жестокие Вы. Начинать всегда трудно. Бывает со всеми... Вопрос имеет место быть

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{
  background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Для таких элементов как p, body, section точку перед название в css ставить не нужно. Если есть точка - значит это буде считаться класом, но body, p, section (допустим) могут иметь свои классы.

Пример:
    <body> 123 </body>
    body{ background: red;}

    <p> 123 </p> 
    p{ font-size: 20px;}


Но:

    <body class="body"> 123 </body>
    .body{ background: red;}

    <p class="paragraph"> 123 </p> 
    .paragraph{ font-size: 20px;}

Answer (score 1):

Пропущен класс же:

```css
.body{
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body class="body"></body>
```

Comment: А минус прокомментировать?

Comment: В вопросе была опечатка

Comment: Но я минус не ставил